# Authorization Policy without model

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1

I need to authorize users on a forum.
So in blade, I have `@can('editPost', $post)` before showing the form to reply to a topic. My `PostPolicy` class has a `editPost` method that validates to true if it's the users own post.

However, the issue appears when I want to do a simple check, like `deletePost()`.  This checks to see if `Auth::user()->isAdmin`

```
public function deletePost(User $user) {
    return Auth::user()->isAdmin;
    // return $user->isAdmin
}
```

However, this won't even get called, since I'm not passing an instance of `Post`

My real world application is much more complicated, but I'm using `isAdmin` as a simple example.

I guess defining `$gate->define('deletePost', 'App\Policies\PostPolicy@deletePost');` in `AuthServiceProvider` could work, but would end up separating my definitions and methods, and ultimately for a large app clutter the `AuthServiceProvider`

Comment: Just for someone else looking for the answer, here's a good way to register a 'global' policy without using a model binding. http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/using-51-authorization-without-models

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you register a policy it is the classname that is used to route checks to the class, so in order to get routed to the policy you can just pass the class name of the type you registered it with.

Try using @can('delete', Post::class) and see if that gets you there

refer to
Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate::firstArgumentCorrespondsToPolicy

EDIT
After a little more diggin I found this
https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/70f75255808ffc96275e6f2f356616dd2e163434#diff-961368895033e553787b301c3be0e17a

so it looks like if you on version 5.1.23 then you will be able to pass a string otherwise your will need to just pass new Post

Answer (score 1):

**In controllers**

```
$this->authorize('<ability>', <Class-With-Rule::class> | <Full-Path-To-Class>);
```

**In Blade view**

```
@can('<ability>', <Class-With-Rule>::class> | <Full-Path-To-Class>)
```

**In Eloquent model**

```
$user->can('<ability>', <Class-With-Rule>::class> | <Full-Path-To-Class>);
```

Answer (score 1):

Methods Without Models:

Some policy methods only receive the currently authenticated user and not an instance of the model they authorize. This situation is most common when authorizing create actions. For example, if you are creating a blog, you may wish to check if a user is authorized to create any posts at all.

When defining policy methods that will not receive a model instance, such as a create method, it will not receive a model instance. Instead, you should define the method as only expecting the authenticated user:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization